# How to write or use two levels of user permissions at once?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have two levels in middleware and it does not work well, then how to write middleware in two levels at once?

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
  $this->middleware('Admin');
  $this->middleware('Teacher');
}
```

I also have this, i want to check that this page is only accessible by admin and teacher, but in writing the code it does not work well and how to write it right?

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 'Admin')
  @elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 'Teacher')
@endif
```

If you can help me in solving this problem i am very grateful

Comment: once you write you own middleware, the condition will manage in side the middleware class. refer here https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#defining-middleware

Answer (score 0):

in my experience i did that using a middleware ..

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    $roles = explode('|',$roles);
    $user = User::find($request->user()->id);
    foreach($user->intRoles as $myRole)
    {
        if(in_array($myRole->role_id, $roles))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'rolePermissions:1|2|3'], function(){
    Route::get('/users',['as'=>'users', 'uses'=>'PagesController@users']);
});
```

> mydomain.com/users will only be accessible for those users who have roles (id) of 1, 2, or 3 ..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate middleware for checking user level. This forces both the conditions and doesn't work the way you want. You need a single middleware to check the user level and pass parameters to it.

Assume we have this middleware named as `access`.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $levels)
{
    $userLevels = explode(',', $levels);

    if (Auth::check() && in_array(Auth::user()->level, $userLevels)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

In your controller add this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'access:Admin,Student']);
}
```

Comment: Why the result remains the same? Page always thrown

Comment: @AgusSuparman be more specific. What is the error you're getting? Also run `php artisan route:list` and share the results.